# In WebDriverJS is it right way to assert only when value exists?

Tags: javascript, testing, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to assert only when value present like below ?

```
var data = await driver.getData();
if(data) {
   assert(data).to.equal('tool');
}
```

is it right approach to handle this here because sometime my data is coming null ? or any other way to handle it ?

Comment: _"Sometimes"_ says to me this is a flakey test. Consider mocking `getData` if it is unreliable.

Comment: if i mock the data then it is not testing what i want ? correct

Comment: Depends on the kind of test you're doing. In what instance would `data` return `null`?

Comment: that is intermittent, calling some third party library api, which is returning null sometimes may be timeout issue ?

Comment: Consider mocking the third party library api? Set your boundaries in your tests so you don't end up relying on other people's code or services.

Comment: ya that could be one solution. but as of now i don't want to touch that library. any other solution you think of ?

Comment: Why would you be touching the library?

Comment: You are saying to mock data here like this ? 
 var data = await driver.getData() || 'mockdummydata' 

here i'm not sure now when my api will return null ? this solution is not so feasible ? do you think so ?

Comment: I can't leave an answer, but my suggestion is to look up how to mock a third party API using your test runner (like Jest). Have it return the data you expect, whether full of information, or null, and write your tests accordingly.

Comment: I understood, thank you, but what do you think this solution 

if(data) {
   assert(data).to.equal('tool');
}

not right ?

Comment: I personally don't like it as the test is not reliable. What would the else case be?

Comment: no else case just run my assertion only when data is not null, or else skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not... conditionals in tests are generally a bad idea. Eg. if data is `false`, what does that test tell you?